# Get values from JSON without key PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am having a JSON that comes in that format without a key

```
["09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00"]
```

I want to do a forech trough the values but it seems that I can't figure it out without a key.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I know how to do it if I have a key for my values. But I dont.

Comment: Decode to __array__, use `foreach`.

Comment: Foreach without a key is `foreach ($array as $value)`. Also covered in the duplicate.

Comment: And `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` will give you the key

Comment: Thanks, I got it!